# Shard Dying Over and Over Discordjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to shard my bot in discord.js. Client.js is my bot.js file

I have this code in my index.js file to shard

```js
const { ShardingManager } = require('discord.js');
const manager = new ShardingManager('./structures/Client.js', {
   token: "token",
})

manager.on('shardCreate', shard => console.log(`Launched shard ${shard.id}`));
manager.spawn();
```

But I keep getting this error:

> (node:27636) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [SHARDING_READY_DIED]: Shard 0's process exited before its Client became ready.

I need some help on sharding it properly

Comment: The Client.js is a bot's code and it initialized the Client instance?

Comment: @LoganDevine yes it is the bot's code and it starts up the bot

Comment: it seems named more like a class definition, is it initialized? as this error means the process exits early

Comment: Maybe you should make it in `client.on('ready')` so that it doesn’t try to do it before the discord client is ready

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple problems I would like to address that might be causing your issue

- Your bot is attempting to be ran before it receives the `ready` event ([@MrMythical](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15781079))
- The file is being recognized as a `Class` and not a script ([@Logan Devine](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14133230))

---

### Running before the "ready" event

When your bot is receiving data from Discord and starting up, it's not ready to start executing code. Discord has to do stuff on their end to make sure that you receive the correct data you're supposed to receive. That's why the `ready` event was created. If your bot tries to execute code before the ready event is emitted, it will exit. Likely, this is what is occcuring with your bot. It's trying to run code before Discord has sent the ready event.

To fix this, it's fairly simple. Just place this in your Client.js file and the bot will listen for the `ready` event

```js
// Replace <client> with whatever variable your Client is
<client>.on("ready", async () => {
  console.log("Online!")
})
```

### Recognizing as a Class

You've named the file with a capital letter. This is typically done when creating a `Class`. However, you're trying to run a script. To fix this, just rename your file with a lowercase letter. If you want to keep the "Client" name on it, just change the uppercase "C" to a lowercase "c". This *should* resolve the issue

### Other Issues

There is one last issue I would like to address. You might be referencing a file that has bad code. Ensure that the `Client.js` inside the `structures` folder has the correct code because you may be accessing the wrong file.